# get the different values from button with same class name

Tags: javascript

I want to get the values from clicking the button with same class name, but whenever I clicked the button it shows undefined.

```js
var clr;
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.color');

function myFunction() {

  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    clr = btn[i].value;
    console.log(clr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <button class="btn" value="#BADA55" onclick="myFunction()"> Yellow </button>
  <button class="btn" value="#10A426" onclick="myFunction()"> Green </button>
  <button class="btn" value="#8787DE" onclick="myFunction()"> Purple </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.color');` gets the div not the buttons. Change that to `const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');`:

```js
var clr;
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    clr = btn[i].value;
    console.log(clr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <button class="btn" value="#BADA55" onclick="myFunction()"> Yellow </button>
  <button class="btn" value="#10A426" onclick="myFunction()"> Green </button>
  <button class="btn" value="#8787DE" onclick="myFunction()"> Purple </button>
</div>
```

If you only want the value from the button being clicked, then change your code to

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  console.log(btn.value);
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <button class="btn" value="#BADA55" onclick="myFunction(this)"> Yellow </button>
  <button class="btn" value="#10A426" onclick="myFunction(this)"> Green </button>
  <button class="btn" value="#8787DE" onclick="myFunction(this)"> Purple </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter care to grow a spine and explain the problem?

Answer (score 1):

do it in this way it will give you exact result

```js
    function myFunction(event) {
        clr = event.target.value;
        console.log(clr);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="color">
      <button class="btn" value="#BADA55" onclick="myFunction(event)"> Yellow </button>
      <button class="btn" value="#10A426" onclick="myFunction(event)"> Green </button>
      <button class="btn" value="#8787DE" onclick="myFunction(event)"> Purple </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should explain your answer and not just say "do it this way". Also, what's the point of using `event.target`? There's no need for `target` as you explicitly pass the object

Comment: on click is event and supposed if we want the values from the event we need to used target, my apology for I am not explaining the answer.

Comment: You're sending in `event` as a parameter but by doing it like you written, it's a variable called `event` that is (supposedly) undefined. Also, onClick isn't sent with an event parameter, it only happens if you use `addEventListener()` to each button.

Comment: sorry to say but its return MouseEvent when I am passing the event in the function I tried myself. please try and let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @RickardElimää : can you please correct me if I am wrong here and please update something

Comment: Sorry. I was talking out of my ass. I will upvote as soon as the edit goes through.

Answer (score 0):

First: scripting where scripting should be (no inline handlers). So add an event listener to the `document`, and let it check if the `target` (the element clicked) has classname `btn`. In that case: iterate through the an Array of elements with className `btn` (`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".btn"))`) using `Array.forEach` to display the values of those elements.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(evt) {
  console.clear();
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("btn")) {
    // a button.btn was clicked, so
    let report = `You clicked button with value ${evt.target.value}. Other .btn values:`;
    let values = [];
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".btn"))
      .forEach(val => val !== evt.target && values.push(val.value));
    console.log(`${report} ${values.join(", ")}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <button class="btn" value="#BADA55"> Yellow </button>
  <button class="btn" value="#10A426"> Green </button>
  <button class="btn" value="#8787DE"> Purple </button>
</div>
```